# Use sharedPreference to save account and password

Tags: android

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity{
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    private EditText accountEdit;

    private EditText passwordEdit;

    private Button login;
    private CheckBox rememberPass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        accountEdit =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.account);
        passwordEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        rememberPass=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.remember_pass);

        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        editor.putBoolean("remember_password",false);
        boolean isRemember = pref.getBoolean("remember_password",false);
        if(isRemember){
            String account = pref.getString("account", "");
            String password =pref.getString("password", "");
            accountEdit.setText(account);
            passwordEdit.setText(password);         
            rememberPass.setChecked(true);
        }

        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String account =accountEdit.getText().toString();
                String password = passwordEdit.getText().toString();

                if (account.equals("admin")&& password.equals("123456")) 
                {   editor = pref.edit();
                    if(rememberPass.isChecked())
                    {
                        editor.putBoolean("remember_password",true);
                        editor.putString("account",account);
                        editor.putString("password",password);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        editor.clear();
                    }
                    editor.commit();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } 
                else 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"account for password is invalid",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }               
            }
        });

     }
 }
```

I use Eclipse to code android.I got an error in LogCat,which is NullPointerException cause by "boolean isRemember = pref.getBoolean("remember_password",false);" 
I don't know why.How to use getBoolean correctly?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `pref=null` at

```
boolean isRemember = pref.getBoolean("remember_password",false);
```

`initialized` it before used

```
SharedPreferences pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the object of the Shared preference than you can use it in yours code

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

than use

```
boolean isRemember = pref.getBoolean("remember_password",false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple way to use prefrences

```
     private SharedPreferences getPrefs;

     //in OnCreate
     getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Activity_Name.this);

     //At insertion value
     getPrefs.edit().putBoolean("Key_Name", false).commit();

     //At fetching Values
     boolean a = getPrefs.getBoolean("Key_Name", false);
```